# Power input management help?

Tags: power-supply, diodes, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, low-power

I'm working on a power supply management circuit for a small 30 mW device powered by alkaline batteries for months in remote locations, used by both skilled and unskilled users. The device will have both an internal and external battery option. I need this circuit to do the following:

- When both an internal and external battery with different voltages are connected, draw power from the higher-voltage battery and prevent the high-voltage battery from trying to charge the low-voltage battery
- Protect against accidental reverse battery connections by users
- Charge a supercapacitor as a backup supply for a safe shutdown (micro-SD card)
- Avoid any unnecessary wasted power

I have a circuit in mind to accomplish this with a bunch of diodes (see below) but I imagine there must be a more elegant way to do this, maybe with a specialized IC that I don't have a search term for. Does anyone know the "right" way to do this? Or, any revisions to the circuit I posted?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqalVp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Looks good to me. You might use schottkies rather than silicon diodes for another 0.4 V drop saved.

Comment: Batteries generally are not good to be recharged if they drop more than 15%. Do you care?

Comment: Be carful, usually the supercap is limited to a maximimum of 2.5 to 2.7 V, and also limit the loading current to this device.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 These are non-rechargeables, so no.

Comment: What are your efficiency specs?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 For comparison, buck-boost converter is 85-90% efficient. System runs on 3.3V, usually at 9 mA (buck-boost output), and up to about 40 mA for ~20 sec every 15 minutes. Saving a few % power consumption matters. Does that answer the question?

Comment: no, I was asking for your expectation limit of efficiency or losses

Comment: that means have you calculated your max, mean % total losses. then are you satisfied with that?